# Unable to resume activity com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfs.zzk

Tags: android, crash-reports, crashlytics

i am facing a weird  problem regarding my app i am seeing many crashes in 
Crashlytics  related to my app and i cant figure it out what is the cause 
this is my log trace

```
 Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.****.****/com.****.****.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfs.zzk(com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafo)' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3226)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1514)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfs.zzk(com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafo)' on a null object reference
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzd.resume(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlv.resume(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView.resume(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.resume(Unknown Source)
       at com.*****.*****.HomeActivity.onResume(HomeActivity.java:461)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1267)
       at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6178)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3211)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1514)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

[image]

is this crash is on devices which has no play services or what? please help me

and this is am doing in HomeActivity `onResume`

```
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            if (adView != null) {
                adView.resume();
                loadBannerAd();
            }
            super.onResume();
    }



  public void loadBannerAd() {
    if (!localPreferences.IsRemovedAdsPurchased()) {
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you update the play services? I started seeing this crashes since 11.8.0

Comment: ` compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0' `
yes

Comment: Maybe switching back to 11.6.2 is an option. This should be reported as a bug to Google, but I cannot reproduce this issue. Can you?

Comment: i tested on many devices but i cant reproduce but as you can see all these devices facing this issue are rare i mean not commonly used i think these devices does not have play services